# Rails Before Filter Usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, basic-authentication

In my Rails 4 app I'm creating an API with access to the `index`, `create`, `show`, `update`, and `destroy` methods in the controller.

For authentication, I'm using HTTP Basic with credentials instead of a username and password (`access_key = username`, `secret_key = password`, and `master_secret_key = password`, for access to certain methods).

I would like the `access_key`/`secret_key` pair to access only the `create`, `update`, `destroy` methods and the `access_key`/`master_secret_key` pair to allow access to the `index` and `show` methods (as well as the other ones).

The authentication works but I'm having trouble telling Rails which way to authenticate based on the request method.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
class Api::V1::TestsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter { :authenticate! || :authenticate_with_master! }
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  def index
  end

  def create
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  protected

  def authenticate!
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |access_key, secret_key|
      @credential = Credentials.find_by_access_key(access_key)
      (@credential.secret_key == secret_key) ? true : false
    end
  end

  def authenticate_with_master!
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |access_key, master_secret_key|
      @credential = Credentials.find_by_access_key(access_key)
      (@user.master_secret_key == master_secret_key) ? true : false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with 'only' parameters for before_filter, and use before_action in Rails 4

```
before_action :authenticate!, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

before_action :authenticate_with_master! , only: [:index, :show]
```

Hope it will help. Thanks